# Dovecot/Postfix cheat on an email that I wrongly received

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I played with `/etc/aliases` and received the email of a coworker. I would like to put it back on his mailbox.
Is there a way to do that cleanly ? I don't want to transfer the email, and if possible if all the mail info could be kept (the header, ip routes etc in the complete mail body) it would be great.

I used gmail as a client. There are just 3 emails so I can do things by hand if necessary

P.S : I have root access to the mail server

Comment: What mail client do you use?  ALPINE, for example, makes this trivial (though an additional informational header is added).

Comment: @MadHatter I use gmail

Comment: Hang on, you said postfix/dovecot.  When did gmail come into this?  Gmail is **not** a client; gmail is a complete, separate, very large (and highly-privacy-intrusive) mail provider.

Comment: @MadHatter dovecot receives the emails, postfix is the pop3 server and gmail read that. And I need to push again to dovecot what gmail pumped out, stripping up gmail information

Comment: Firstly, postfix will receive the emails and dovecot will allow them to be read; you have accidentally inverted MTA and IMAP/POP server.  Secondly, are you saying that in addition to its own mailstore you've given gmail access to your pop/imap server?  In any case I'm afraid I wouldn't use gmail in a month of Sundays, so if that really is your mail client I can't help, as I have no idea if it can do an SMTP resend.

Comment: @MadHatter there is no way to send an email to postfix, then go in the /var/mail and edit the file by hand to remove the mess ?

Comment: That is most definitely not what I said.  There are mail clients that can perform SMTP redelivery, that is, reinject a mail into the MTA's input stream without modifying any of the existing headers (though four additional informational resend headers are added, and there will of course be mail server log entries).  [ALPINE](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/) is one such.  It is very likely that there are others.  I don't know how to do it with gmail.

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to go to the trouble of setting up [ALPINE](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/) as a mail client, to talk to your existing dovecot IMAP server and postfix SMTP server, you can perform mail redelivery by selecting the email then using the `B` command ("Bounce"; I don't know why they call it that).

You will be asked for the address to which you wish to bounce the message; enter your desired recipient's address, press return, and confirm the operation with `Y`.

The message will  appear in his INBOX with addittional headers similar to these:

```
Resent-Date: Mon, 11 Aug 2014 08:22:13 +0100 (BST)
Resent-From: Your Name <thomas@example.com>
Resent-To: new.recipient@example.org
Resent-Subject: Re: Original Subject Line Here
```

There will also be additional `Received: from` headers arising from this new SMTP transaction, but all the original header information, including routing, date, subject and so on, should be preserved.

Please note that questions about the gory details of setting up ALPINE, getting it to authenticate against your existing mail server for reading and sending, and so on, are probably off-topic for Server Fault.

It is likely that some other mail clients can do a similar operation, but I can't say how they can be told to do it, nor whether gmail is one of them.

Comment: so the person will see that it bounced from me, there is no other way ?

Comment: Only if they read the headers.  If you want this to be completely transparent, you'll need root access on the mail server.

Comment: I have root access

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the mail storage at file system level, you could just move the files over to the other inbox with mv. works best with maildir as storage layout/system.

Comment: The files are not there anymore as my gmail read the content of the mailbox